# A* infinite loop

Tags: java, list, infinite-loop, path-finding, a-star

I'm trying to implement an A* algorithm for a pathfinding problem.

It works, like 9 out of 10 times, but at some points I get a (possibly) infinite loop, and the program doesn't find the optimal path. Can you see why it happens?

A*:

```
import java.util.*;


public abstract class AStar<T>
{
            private class Path implements Comparable{
                            public T point;
                            public Double f;
                            public Double g;
                            public Path parent;


                            public Path(){
                                            parent = null;
                                            point = null;
                                            g = f = 0.0;
                            }


                            public Path(Path p){
                                            this();
                                            parent = p;
                                            g = p.g;
                                            f = p.f;
                            }


                            public int compareTo(Object o){
                                            Path p = (Path)o;
                                            return (int)(f - p.f);
                            }


                            public T getPoint(){
                                            return point;
                            }


                            public void setPoint(T p){
                                            point = p;
                            }
            }


            protected abstract boolean isGoal(T node);


            protected abstract Double g(T from, T to);


            protected abstract Double h(T from, T to);



            protected abstract List<T> generateSuccessors(T node);


            private PriorityQueue<Path> paths;
            private HashMap<T, Double> mindists;
            private Double lastCost;
            private int expandedCounter;


            public int getExpandedCounter(){
                            return expandedCounter;
            }


            public AStar(){
                            paths = new PriorityQueue<Path>();
                            mindists = new HashMap<T, Double>();
                            expandedCounter = 0;
                            lastCost = 0.0;
            }



            protected Double f(Path p, T from, T to){
                            Double g =  g(from, to) + ((p.parent != null) ? p.parent.g : 0.0);
                            Double h = h(from, to);

                            p.g = g;
                            p.f = g + h;

                            return p.f;
            }


            private void expand(Path path){
                            T p = path.getPoint();
                            Double min = mindists.get(path.getPoint());


                            if(min == null || min.doubleValue() > path.f.doubleValue())
                                            mindists.put(path.getPoint(), path.f);
                            else
                                            return;

                            List<T> successors = generateSuccessors(p);

                            for(T t : successors){
                                            Path newPath = new Path(path);
                                            newPath.setPoint(t);
                                            f(newPath, path.getPoint(), t);
                                            paths.offer(newPath);
                            }

                            expandedCounter++;
            }

            public Double getCost(){
                            return lastCost;
            }

            public List<T> compute(T start){
                            try{
                                            Path root = new Path();
                                            root.setPoint(start);

                                            /* Needed if the initial point has a cost.  */
                                            f(root, start, start);

                                            expand(root);

                                            for(;;){
                                                            Path p = paths.poll();

                                                            if(p == null){
                                                                            lastCost = Double.MAX_VALUE;
                                                                            return null;
                                                            }

                                                            T last = p.getPoint();

                                                            lastCost = p.g;

                                                            if(isGoal(last)){
                                                                            LinkedList<T> retPath = new LinkedList<T>();

                                                                            for(Path i = p; i != null; i = i.parent){
                                                                                            retPath.addFirst(i.getPoint());
                                                                            }

                                                                            return retPath;
                                                            }
                                                            expand(p);
                                            }
                            }
                            catch(Exception e){
                                            e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            return null;

            }
```

}

And the pathfinding class with the main:

```
import java.util.*;

public class PathFinder extends AStar<PathFinder.Node>
{
            private int[][] map;
            private int endx;
            private int endy;

            public static class Node{
                            public int x;
                            public int y;
                            Node(int x, int y){
                                            this.x = x; 
                                            this.y = y;
                            }
                           public String toString(){
                                            return "(" + x + ", " + y + ") ";
                            }
                            public int getX(){
                                return x;
                            }
                            public int getY(){
                                return y;
                            }
}               public PathFinder(int[][] map, int endx, int endy){
                            this.map = map;
                            this.endx=endx;
                            this.endy=endy;
            }

            protected boolean isGoal(Node node){
                            return (node.x == endx) && (node.y == endy);
            }

            protected Double g(Node from, Node to){

                            if(from.x == to.x && from.y == to.y){

                           //   System.out.println("To x1 " + to.x);
                         //     System.out.println("To y1 " + to.y);
                                            return 0.0;}

                            if(map[to.y][to.x] == 1){
                                //System.out.println("To x2 " + to.x);
                            //  System.out.println("To y2 " + to.y);

                                            return 1.0;}

                            return Double.MAX_VALUE;
            }

            protected Double h(Node from, Node to){

                           return new Double(Math.abs(endx - to.x) + Math.abs(endy - to.y));
            }

            protected List<Node> generateSuccessors(Node node){
                            List<Node> ret = new LinkedList<Node>();
                            int x = node.x;
                            int y = node.y;
                            if(y < map[0].length-1 && map[y+1][x] == 1)
                                            ret.add(new Node(x, y+1));

                            if(x <map.length-1 && map[y][x+1] == 1)
                                            ret.add(new Node(x+1, y));

                            if(y !=0 && map[y-1][x] == 1)
                                            ret.add(new Node(x, y-1));

                            if(x !=0 && map[y][x-1] == 1)
                                            ret.add(new Node(x-1, y));

                            return ret;
            }

            public static void main(String [] args){
                            WorldGenerator gen = new WorldGenerator();

            int ammountOfBlocks =200;
            int width = 25;
            int length = 25;
            int startX = 1;
            int startY = 1;
            int endX = 24;
            int endY = 24;
            int[][] map = gen.createWorld(ammountOfBlocks,width,length,startX,startY,endX,endY);
            int a=map.length;
            int b=map[0].length;
            int[][] map2=new int[b][a];
            for(int i=0; i<map.length; i++){
                for(int j=0; j<map[0].length;j++)
                {map2[j][i]=map[i][j];
                }
            }
                            PathFinder pf = new PathFinder(map,endX,endY);


                           /* for(int i = 0; i < map.length; i++){
                                            for(int j = 0; j < map[0].length; j++)
                                                            System.out.print(map[i][j] + " ");
                                            System.out.println();
                            }*/

                            long begin = System.currentTimeMillis();

                            List<Node> nodes = pf.compute(new PathFinder.Node(startX,startY));

                            long end = System.currentTimeMillis();


                            System.out.println("Time = " + (end - begin) + " ms" );
                            //System.out.println("Expanded = " + pf.getExpandedCounter());
                            System.out.println("Cost = " + pf.getCost());

                            if(nodes == null)
                                            System.out.println("No path");
                            else{

                                            for(int i=0; i<nodes.size();i++){
                                                            Node n=nodes.get(i);
                                                            int x= n.getX();
                                                            int y= n.getY();
                                                            map[x][y]=4;
                            }
                           /* for(int i = 0; i < map.length; i++){
                                            for(int j = 0; j < map[0].length; j++)
                                                            System.out.print(map[i][j] + " ");
                                            System.out.println();
                            }*/

            }

            }
```

}

the WorldGenerator class only generates a 2 dimensional array of 1s and 0s.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shooting from my hip here, but if you want to use a 'direct line distance' as your heuristic you have a bug in your code.

The current heuristic is: *The node with the smallest sum of delta x and y is closest.*

Let's say we have a five x five grid and the target is in 2,2 then using this heuristic 2,0 would be equally optimal as 1,1 which of course is wrong.

Try using Pythagoras for a new heuristic: *The node with the shortest distance to the end is the closest.*

```
protected Double h(Node from, Node to) {
    int dx = Math.abs(endx - to.x);
    int dy = Math.abs(endy - to.y);
    return new Double(Math.sqrt(dx*dx) + (dy*dy));
}
```

This would make your algorithm use an http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Admissible_heuristic which is a criteria for A*: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_star#Admissibility_and_optimality

Hope this helps.

---

A solution that works for me:

**AStar.java**

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.PriorityQueue;

public abstract class AStar<T> {

    private class Path<T> implements Comparable {

        public T point;
        public Double f;
        public Double g;
        public Path<T> parent;

        public Path() {
            parent = null;
            point = null;
            g = f = 0.0;
        }

        public Path(Path<T> p) {
            this();
            parent = p;
            g = p.g;
            f = p.f;
        }

        @Override
        public int compareTo(Object o) {
            AStar.Path p = (AStar.Path) o;
            return (int) (f - p.f);
        }

        public T getPoint() {
            return point;
        }

        public void setPoint(T p) {
            point = p;
        }
    }

    protected abstract boolean isGoal(T node);

    protected abstract Double g(T from, T to);

    protected abstract Double h(T from, T to);

    protected abstract List<T> generateSuccessors(T node, T parent);
    private PriorityQueue<AStar.Path> paths;
    private HashMap<T, Double> mindists;
    private Double lastCost;
    private int expandedCounter;

    public int getExpandedCounter() {
        return expandedCounter;
    }

    public AStar() {
        paths = new PriorityQueue<>();
        mindists = new HashMap<>();
        expandedCounter = 0;
        lastCost = 0.0;
    }

    protected Double f(AStar.Path p, T from, T to) {
        Double g = g(from, to) + ((p.parent != null) ? p.parent.g : 0.0);
        Double h = h(from, to);

        p.g = g;
        p.f = g + h;

        return p.f;
    }

    private void expand(Path<T> path) {
        if (expandedCounter > 1000000) {
            return;
        }
        T p = path.getPoint();
        Double min = mindists.get(path.getPoint());


        if (min == null || min.doubleValue() > path.f.doubleValue()) {
            mindists.put(path.getPoint(), path.f);
        } else {
            return;
        }

        List<T> successors = generateSuccessors(p, path.parent != null ? path.parent.getPoint() : null);

        for (T t : successors) {
            AStar.Path newPath = new AStar.Path(path);
            newPath.setPoint(t);
            f(newPath, path.getPoint(), t);
            paths.offer(newPath);
        }

        expandedCounter++;
    }

    public Double getCost() {
        return lastCost;
    }

    public List<T> compute(T start) {
        try {
            AStar.Path root = new AStar.Path();
            root.setPoint(start);

            /*
             * Needed if the initial point has a cost.
             */
            f(root, start, start);

            expand(root);

            for (;;) {
                Path<T> p = paths.poll();

                if (p == null) {
                    lastCost = Double.MAX_VALUE;
                    return null;
                }

                T last = p.getPoint();

                lastCost = p.g;

                if (isGoal(last)) {
                    LinkedList<T> retPath = new LinkedList<T>();

                    for (Path<T> i = p; i != null; i = i.parent) {
                        retPath.addFirst(i.getPoint());
                    }

                    return retPath;
                }
                expand(p);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;

    }
}
```

**PathFinder.java**

```
package playground;

import java.util.*;

public class PathFinder extends AStar<PathFinder.Node> {

    private int[][] map;
    private int endx;
    private int endy;

    public static class Node {

        public int x;
        public int y;

        Node(int x, int y) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }

        public String toString() {
            return "(" + x + ", " + y + ") ";
        }

        public int getX() {
            return x;
        }

        public int getY() {
            return y;
        }
    }

    public PathFinder(int[][] map, int endx, int endy) {
        this.map = map;
        this.endx = endx;
        this.endy = endy;
    }

    protected boolean isGoal(Node node) {
        return (node.x == endx) && (node.y == endy);
    }

    protected Double g(Node from, Node to) {

        if (from.x == to.x && from.y == to.y) {

            //   System.out.println("To x1 " + to.x);
            //     System.out.println("To y1 " + to.y);
            return 0.0;
        }

        if (map[to.y][to.x] == 1) {
            //System.out.println("To x2 " + to.x);
            //  System.out.println("To y2 " + to.y);

            return 1.0;
        }

        return Double.MAX_VALUE;
    }

    protected Double h(Node from, Node to) {
        int dx = Math.abs(endx - to.x);
        int dy = Math.abs(endy - to.y);
        return new Double(Math.sqrt(dx * dx) + (dy * dy));
        //return new Double(Math.abs(endx - to.x) + Math.abs(endy - to.y));
    }

    @Override
    protected List<Node> generateSuccessors(Node node, Node parent) {
        List<Node> ret = new LinkedList<Node>();
        int x = node.x;
        int y = node.y;
        if (y < map[0].length - 1 && map[y + 1][x] == 1 && (parent == null || (parent != null && !(parent.x == x && parent.y == y + 1)))) {
            ret.add(new Node(x, y + 1));
        }

        if (x < map.length - 1 && map[y][x + 1] == 1 && (parent == null || (parent != null && !(parent.x == x + 1 && parent.y == y)))) {
            ret.add(new Node(x + 1, y));
        }

        if (y != 0 && map[y - 1][x] == 1 && (parent == null || (parent != null && !(parent.x == x && parent.y == y - 1)))) {
            ret.add(new Node(x, y - 1));
        }

        if (x != 0 && map[y][x - 1] == 1 && (parent == null || (parent != null && !(parent.x == x - 1 && parent.y == y)))) {
            ret.add(new Node(x - 1, y));
        }

        return ret;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int ammountOfBlocks = 200;
        int width = 25;
        int length = 25;
        int startX = 1;
        int startY = 1;
        int endX = 24;
        int endY = 24;
        int[][] map = {
            {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
            {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
            {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
            {1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
            {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1},
            {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
            {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
            {1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
            {1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1},
            {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
            {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1},
            {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1},
            {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1},
            {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1},
            {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1},
            {1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
            {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
            {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
            {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
            {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1},
            {0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1},
            {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
            {1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
            {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0},
            {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}
        };
        int a = map.length;
        int b = map[0].length;
        int[][] map2 = new int[b][a];
        for (int i = 0; i < map.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < map[0].length; j++) {
                map2[j][i] = map[i][j];
            }
        }
        PathFinder pf = new PathFinder(map, endX, endY);


        /*
         * for(int i = 0; i < map.length; i++){ for(int j = 0; j <
         * map[0].length; j++) System.out.print(map[i][j] + " ");
         * System.out.println(); }
         */

        long begin = System.currentTimeMillis();

        List<Node> nodes = pf.compute(new PathFinder.Node(startX, startY));

        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();


        System.out.println("Time = " + (end - begin) + " ms");
        //System.out.println("Expanded = " + pf.getExpandedCounter());
        System.out.println("Cost = " + pf.getCost());

        if (nodes == null) {
            System.out.println("No path");
        } else {

            for (int i = 0; i < nodes.size(); i++) {
                Node n = nodes.get(i);
                int x = n.getX();
                int y = n.getY();
                map[x][y] = 4;
            }

            for(int i = 0; i < map.length; i++){ 
                for(int j = 0; j < map[0].length; j++) 
                    System.out.print(map[i][j] + " ");

                System.out.println(); 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the comment, but it's not it. The same thing keeps happening. Thank you very much though! 
On a 25by25 with 50 obstacles, it happens in like 10 tries.

Comment: Hi again, does your map generator indicate the goal with anything? Or is every cell except the obstacles 1? I initiated map to a 25x25 of 1's and it works here. That is, I change h() and it finds a path.

Comment: Hello! Everything is 1 except for the obstacles.
And yes, it works in many cases, but at one point it just decides not to give me the answer anymore and keeps going until it runs out of memmory.

Comment: Do you have a repeatable set of values that never work?
Such as a start pos, end pos and some obstacles?

Are you sure it's not the world generator that blocks the target pos out? It would be an explanation for it not to work, if there are no paths available.

Comment: -The world is always randomly generated.
-I keep the end and start coordinates the same.
-I always have the same ammount of obstacles.

I thought that aswell, that the problem is the position of some obstacles, but didn't see any connection yet.

Comment: As your algorithm is deterministic, and you're only having the problem some times I think the main problem is with the generator as that is the only source of randomness. If you're able to give me a recipe for fail (start, end and obstacles) I won't give up until we've fixed this. Sorry for spamming wikis but here is another one: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maze_generation_algorithm#Recursive_division_method :)

Comment: http://tinypic.com/r/2wntu6w/6

Thank you very much!

This is a situation where it goes on forever.

Comment: could you paste the text somewhere so I don't have to type it in? I'm off now but I'll have a look later this evening. Let me know if you find a solution

Comment: The "map", or which text do you mean?

Comment: Adding a comment to let you know I edited my answer with code that made it work. Basically I just make sure the path never backtracks to the parent node. The path is therefore never immediately cyclic (a , b, a) though it still may do (a, b, c, a) but because your heuristic is admissible it never will.